# How to make rotate to 45 deg and animate change left same time?

Tags: jquery, css, rotation

How to make in duration rotate angle to 45 deg and stop?
I can't find the way make `angle` in below demo increase to 45 during animate change margin-left, 
how to do it??

http://jsfiddle.net/8tP9D/37/

```
var angle = 0;

$('.btn').click(function(){
$("#a").animate ({
    "margin-left": "+=200px" 
    },
    {
    step: function (now, fx) {
        angle += 1;
        $(this).css({
            "-moz-transform":"rotate("+angle+"deg)",
            "-webkit-transform":"rotate("+angle+"deg)",
            "-ms-transform":"rotate("+angle+"deg)",
            "-o-transform":"rotate("+angle+"deg)"
        });
    },
    duration: 300 }, "linear");
});
```

Comment: Are you asking a question or demonstrating how to do it? If you are asking a question, please clarify what is wrong with what you have. If you are not asking a question, you shouldn't post it as a question.

Comment: Why do you need to step through each angle rotation? If you animate to the end angle it will work just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to increment the rotation each step as you can use `.animate` and give it a target value and it will automatically step to that value (and fluently)

If I were doing this, I would use `.css` and CSS transitions as it performs much better than jQuery's `transform`. That would look like the following

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $("#a").css ({
    "-moz-transform":"translateX(200px) rotate(45deg)",
    "-webkit-transform":"translateX(200px) rotate(45deg)",
    "-ms-transform":"translateX(200px) rotate(45deg)",
    "transform":"translateX(200px) rotate(45deg)"
  });
});
```

```css
#a {
  margin-top:25px;
  margin-left:25px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transition:.3s linear;
  -moz-transition:.3s linear;
  -ms-transition:.3s linear;
  transition:.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">btn</div>
<ul>
  <li id="a">
    <span>content</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For performance I would recommend using vanilla javascript for this as well

Comment: Thanks !! you mentioned vanilla javascript, you mean this http://vanilla-js.com ?

Comment: @user1775888 Yes, but vanilla javascript = javascript (: There is no difference